# Setup proxy for Docker Dind service

Tags: docker, proxy, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I'm using Gitlab CI/CD pipeline and I'm trying to make publish job work.
My network is protected by company policy, so I need to use Proxy. I have setup proxy configs for my Docker. And it work well untill `docker build` job is executed.

My publish job looks like this:

```yaml
  publish_test:
  stage: publish
  image: docker:19.03.1
  only:
    - test
  services:
    - docker:19.03.1-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE: ${IMAGE}
  before_script:
    - mkdir tmp
    - cp docker/Dockerfile build/libs/backend_v2-*.jar tmp
    - cd tmp
    - echo ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} | docker login ${CI_REGISTRY} -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} --password-stdin
  script:
    - docker pull ${IMAGE} || true
    - docker tag ${IMAGE} ${IMAGE}-backup || true
    - docker push ${IMAGE}-backup || true
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t ${IMAGE} .
    - docker push ${IMAGE}
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build/
```

The problem is here: `docker build -t ${IMAGE} .`
He can't pull Docker image due to connection error:

```
 Step 1/4 : FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11
 Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

So far I've tried multiple solutions, nothing of which worked for me:
1. Tried to add proxy variables into Gitlab Variables and put proxy configs into this job like this:

```
- export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY};
- export https_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY};
- export no_proxy=${NO_PROXY};
```

2. Tried to use `build-arg` params:

`docker build --progress --build-arg ${HTTP_PROXY} --build-arg ${HTTPS_PROXY} --build-arg ${NO_PROXY} -t ${IMAGE} .`

3. I've found my case in Gitlab Docs - https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/proxy.html#proxy-settings-when-using-dind-service. Tried to follow instruction there, it didn't work.

How I can make it work for me? I need to setup proxy settings for this Docker build job, so that it could pull necessary Docker image. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to re-export envs that are configured as GitLab Variables. Add script `env | grep proxy` or `env | grep PROXY` to your pipeline to see that envs are present.
2. Assumming your proxy envs look like this `HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3001` build command should be `docker build --progress --build-arg http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} ...`

Looks like you used wrongly build arguments `--build-arg ${HTTP_PROXY}` should be `--build-arg http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}` and the same for `https_proxy` and `no_proxy`.

Comment: `$ docker build --build-arg http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} --build-arg https_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} no_proxy=${NO_PROXY} -t ${IMAGE} .
 "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
 See 'docker build --help'.
 Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
 Build an image from a Dockerfile
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`          

Thank you for the response. I tried to do like you advised and got this syntax error.

Comment: Add `--build-arg` before each env. `--build-arg https_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} no_proxy=${NO_PROXY}` -> `--build-arg https_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} --build-arg no_proxy=${NO_PROXY}`

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks :) 
But unfortunately it didn't help. I get the same connection error after this.     
               
`$ docker build --build-arg http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} --build-arg https_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} --build-arg no_proxy=${NO_PROXY} -t ${IMAGE} .
 Step 1/4 : FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11
 Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Comment: Are you using custom executor? Can you connect to this executor and manually test connection with e.g. `docker run -ti azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11 bash`?

Comment: Yes, I can. That's strange, and I can't figure out why at the moment. Looks like problem is somewhere on the Gitlab Runner side, but where exactly. I can successfully execute both `docker run -ti azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11` and `docker pull azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11` manually

Comment: I'll try checking it also manually from within dind image. As a side note, wouldn't it be easier to use shell runner for your project?

Comment: Well I checked from inside dind service and it worked fine as well. I read about some cases where restarting and updating docker service worked. If you suspect it is a CI runner problem then you could try with different runner (shared runners should do).